# List of primitives from vector of string C++

Tags: c++

I have been searching for this answer for a week. I haven't found a solution. I would like to know if it is possible to declare the name of a primitive from a vector of strings. 
Meaning if I have a class that accepts a string, pushes it back into a vector of strings, I want to then declare a primitive of float with the name of each string.

```
 vector<string> myVec;
 Test::setCoordinate(string &myStr){
  myVec.push_back(myStr);
 }
```

Now I would like each name to be a container for a variable of type float.

Comment: What do you mean by "primitives"?

Comment: Dynamic variable creation (if that's what you're trying to do) is a bad, messy idea. It's rarely if ever necessary.

Comment: Maybe a `std::map<std::string, float>` is what you are looking for?

Comment: The values I want to call are stored in a tree type and do not know the values beforehand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that is not possible. C++ does not have any dynamic code generation features that would allow variables to be named from run-time data such as strings.

The closest you can get is something like:

```
std::map<std::string, float> values;
values["f1"] = 0.3;
values["f2"] = 0.6;
```

Comment: Wait, since when does leaving out `f` as in `0.3f` not issue a warning?

Comment: It's a literal of type `double`, why would it warn?

Comment: a `double` saved into a `float` might cause narrowing, not?

Comment: @GillBates: That is (usually) a narrowing conversion. Whether the compiler warns about it...well, probably not, at least when you're using a floating literal that's within the range that can be represented as a float (as is the case here). A warning would be more likely if you tried to assign something like `1e100`, which won't normally fit in a `float` at all.

Comment: Narrowing conversions do not require diagnostics except inside braced-init-lists. Sure, you can crank up warning levels (e.g. with `-Wconversion`) to warn about it, but the answer to "since when does leaving out f as in 0.3f not issue a warning?" is that it never does, by default. Not even with `-Wall -Wextra` using GCC or Clang.